Endnote Hyperlinks to Include Both the Endnote Mark and Its Content
This post looks for an extension of the answers given in Why \let\footnote=\endnote Disables Hyperlinks and How to Fix It?.
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%  
  pdftex,
  bookmarks=false,bookmarksopen=false,
  colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red,urlcolor=blue,
  breaklinks=true,
  hyperfootnotes=true
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\usepackage{hyperendnote}

\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=3.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
               
\chapter[Chapter 1]{}
This is a sentence.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\theendnotes
\end{document}

which produces:



QUESTION: In the endnotes hyperlink(s), how may one link the entire content of the endnote (in addition to the endnote mark)?
Thank you.
